# how to fully wrap an absolute position div with a relative position div?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to fully wrap an absolute position div with a relative position div without defining height and width pixel values of outer relative position div? Here i can not see red border of `"outerrelativediv"` as covered around `"innerabsolutediv"`.

```
<div id="outerrelativediv" style="position:relative;display:inline-block;border:1px solid red;">
  <div id="innerabsolutediv" style="position:absolute;display:inline-block;">
    SOMETEXT HERE!!!
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L3bytwnj/

Comment: what reason then to be absolute for inner? Let it to be relative too

Comment: No, not without giving it height of some kind, or at least letting it take the height from another normal flow child.

Comment: no reason i am just curious if it is possible?

Comment: Sure, not. Absolute is for positioning inside relative, you can move it inside, stretch to container size, but not to change container size. Absolute blocks are not in content flow.

Comment: absolute (and fixed) position takes the element of the flux, so what you try to do won't work. inline block on its own on parent will do (so will:  inline-table, table,table-cell, inline-flex,or float or absolute or fixed ) it's about positionning in CSS (display, float, position, direction, ...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple answer is: ***no***.

When you give an element `position: absolute;` you take it **out of the normal flow of content**. If it is the only child of its parent, the  parent will have no flow content. It will be empty.

Normally, empty `html` elements have `width` and `height` values of `0` and, in turn, do not take space in the normal flow of content. There are exceptions that can cause an empty element to be rendered, such as being a child of a `flex` parent that is stretching its children. But at some point along the chain of parents, one of them has to have a set dimension or at least some content (possibly in a sibling chain) that generates some `height`/`width` or otherwise they will all be just a big chain of empty elements not being rendered.

Additionally, `padding`and `border` attributes on a child are  generating `width` / `height` on parent elements, even when the child does not have content.